# Determine if an attribute of Entity is dirty with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm developing using J2EE, with JPA and Hibernate (in 4.0. version) for the management of the persistence of data.

I need to change, for some entities of my project, the default dirty-checking mechanism of Hibernate so, surfing the web, I've found that there is the possibility to extends the [EmptyInterceptor](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/EmptyInterceptor.html) class, to override the findDirty method usually called from Hibernate for operations of persist or update.
However, this method works with the whole Entity.
In fact, the signature of findDirty is:

```
public int[] findDirty(Object entity,
                   Serializable id,
                   Object[] currentState,
                   Object[] previousState,
                   String[] propertyNames,
                   Type[] types)
```

My question is: there is a method that works with only a property of the Entity, which can be itself another Entity but also a String, in order to determine if it is dirty, and in positive case return its index in the Entity?

What I mean is if there is a method similar to findDirty (for behavior) but instead of taking in input the whole Entity, it takes only one attribute of it, and determines if this attribute is dirty or not comparing its current state and its previous state.

Comment: `there is a method that works with only a property of the Entity, which can be itself another Entity but also a String, in order to determine if it is dirty, and in positive case return its index in the Entity?` -- what do you mean by this? can you please elaborate

Comment: I don't think hibernate have any such api that helps in this case, I think you can implement the required behavior by extending the interceptor.